# mupen64plus - Installation Advice 12.04

Tags: 12.04, video, games

I am trying to install mupen64plus. I have tried 2 ways.

one by downloading the binary and using sudo ./install.sh. That installed to usr/local. However when attempting to run it failed to work.

So I installed mupen64plus from a ppa and then installed the mupen64plus package.

However I still receive this error.

```
Mupen64Plus Console User-Interface Version 1.99.4

UI-console: attached to core library 'Mupen64Plus Core' version 1.99.4
            Includes support for Dynamic Recompiler.
Core: Goodname: Super Smash Bros. (E) (M3) [f1]
Core: Name: SMASH BROTHERS
Core: MD5: 99C1AB76126B7BADFA9023D50DCA1430
Core: CRC: 593bd58b c330786c
Core: Imagetype: .z64 (native)
Core: Rom size: 33554432 bytes (or 32 Mb or 256 Megabits)
Core: Version: 1449
Core: Manufacturer: Nintendo
Core: Country: Europe (0x50)
UI-Console: Cheat codes disabled.
dlopen('./mupen64plus-video-rice.so') error: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dlopen('./mupen64plus-video-rice.so') error: libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
UI-console: using Video plugin: <dummy>
Audio Error: Core emulator broken; no CoreAPIVersionFunc() function found.
Error: Audio plugin library './mupen64plus-audio-sdl.so' failed to start.
```

If you have gor mupen64plus to work on 12.04 can you advise the steps needed to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it has some pre-built binaries which are linked a newer version of `libpng` than is available in Ubuntu 12.04.

If you installed to `/usr/local` though, and didn't uninstall it from there, it will still be using that version if you installed from packages afterward (which probably install to /usr instead). You will need to uninstall the version which was installed to the /usr/local prefix first.

Answer (score 1):

Mupen 64 Plus is available in the repositories, any reason you didn't try that way?

In terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install mupen64plus
```

Or use the Ubuntu Software Center!

## [mupen64plus](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mupen64plus) [image: Install mupen64plus]

Version is a bit outdated (1.99.4 for Ubuntu 12.04) but for me it runs Zelda Ocarina of Time and Super Mario 64 perfectly.

It works out-of-the-box with default settings, but I changed the auto-generated config file at `~/.config/mupen64plus/mupen64plus.cfg` to use Glide64 video instead of the default Rice plugin. I've also made a few tweaks for my controller, and set it to start in fullscreen (since Glide64 cannot switch windowed/fullscreen in 1.99.4)